# Difference in performance Sigmoid vs. Softmax

Tags: image-classification, training, loss-function, softmax, sigmoid

For the same Binary Image Classification task, if in the final layer I use `1 node` with *`Sigmoid`* activation function and *`binary_crossentropy`* loss function, then the training process goes through pretty smoothly (92% accuracy after 3 epochs on validation data).

However, if I change the final layer to `2 nodes` and use the *`Softmax`* activation function with *`sparse_categorical_crossentropy`* loss function, then the model doesn't seem to learn at all and stuck at 55% accuracy (the ratio of the negative class).

Is this difference in performance normal? I thought for a binary classification task, `Sigmoid with Binary Crossentropy` and `Softmax with Sparse Categorical Crossentropy` should output similar if not identical results? Or did I do something wrong?

Note: I use Adam optimizer and there is a single label column containing 0s and 1s.

**Edit**: Code for the 2 cases

*Case 1*: Sigmoid with binary_crossentropy

```
def addTopModelMobilNetV1(bottom_model, num_classes):
    top_model = bottom_model.output
    top_model = layers.GlobalAveragePooling2D()(top_model)
    top_model = layers.Dense(1024, activation='relu')(top_model)
    top_model = layers.Dense(1024, activation='relu')(top_model)
    top_model = layers.Dense(512, activation='relu')(top_model)
    top_model = layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')(top_model)
    
    return top_model

fc_head = addTopModelMobilNetV1(mobilnet_model, num_classes)
model = Model(inputs=mobilnet_model.input, outputs=fc_head)
# print(model.summary())

earlystopping_cb = callbacks.EarlyStopping(patience=3, restore_best_weights=True)
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer=optimizers.Adam(), metrics=['accuracy'])
history = model.fit_generator(generator=train_generator, 
                              steps_per_epoch=train_df.shape[0]//TRAIN_BATCH_SIZE, 
                              validation_data = val_generator,
                              epochs = 10,
                              callbacks = [earlystopping_cb]
                              )
```

*Case 2*: Softmax with sparse_categorical_crossentropy

```
def addTopModelMobilNetV1(bottom_model, num_classes):
    top_model = bottom_model.output
    top_model = layers.GlobalAveragePooling2D()(top_model)
    top_model = layers.Dense(1024, activation='relu')(top_model)
    top_model = layers.Dense(1024, activation='relu')(top_model)
    top_model = layers.Dense(512, activation='relu')(top_model)
    top_model = layers.Dense(2, activation='softmax')(top_model)
    
    return top_model

fc_head = addTopModelMobilNetV1(mobilnet_model, num_classes)
model = Model(inputs=mobilnet_model.input, outputs=fc_head)

earlystopping_cb = callbacks.EarlyStopping(patience=3, restore_best_weights=True)

model.compile(loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy', optimizer=optimizers.Adam(), metrics=['accuracy'])

history = model.fit_generator(generator=train_generator, 
                                  steps_per_epoch=train_df.shape[0]//TRAIN_BATCH_SIZE, 
                                  validation_data = val_generator,
                                  epochs = 10,
                                  callbacks = [earlystopping_cb]
                                  )
```

Comment: Why should these different activation functions give similar results?

Comment: I think you might read thoroughly the answers in this page. Believe me you will find the answer:    ```https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/233658/softmax-vs-sigmoid-function-in-logistic-classifier```

Comment: @NikosM. Because the softmax function is an extension of sigmoid that works for any number of classes >= 2 and not just 2. For binary classification (2 classes), they are the same.

Comment: @Hamzah I checked out the link and it does confirm my confusion since for 2 classes softmax and sigmoid are identical. Did I use the softmax activation incorrectly somehow?

Comment: Can you elaborate how you get the predicted class when using 2 final nodes with softmax?

Comment: Even better share the code

Comment: @NikosM. I added the code. I just tried to fit it and look at the training result. I've also tried to test a random image with the model and it outputs the correct format, for example [0.01, 0.99].

Comment: Yes I see you use a pretrained model and add layers on top. Seems strange..

Comment: @NikosM. "top" actually refers to the output layers, so I didn't include top and add a custom top to match my dataset's number of classes, be able to change activation function, etc. I thought this is standard for transfer learning?

Answer (score 0):

It is based on the output classes if they are mutually exclusive or not. For example in a multi-label classification problem, we use multiple sigmoid functions for each output because it is considered as multiple binary classification problems.

But if the output classes are mutually exclusive. In this case, the best choice is to use softmax, because it will give a probability for each class and summation of all probabilities = 1. For instance, if the image is a dog, the output will be 90% a dag and 10% a cat.

In binary classification, the only output is not mutually exclusive, we definitely use the sigmoid function. Because there are no other classes to apply the Mutual exclusivity.

You can find a summary here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55936594/16310106

Comment: The output of Binary classification should be mutually exclusive no? It can only be 0 or 1 and not both at the same time. I think you're confusing this with multi-label classification (where you need to use sigmoid instead of softmax since the outputs are not mutually exclusive). 
I understand we can use Sigmoid for binary classification, but why can't we use the Softmax activation function for binary classification? Mathematically it should work right?